# How to get WatiN to scan dynamically loaded content?

Tags: testing, watin

The situation is that I have a page that uses some AJAX calls to retrieve content from the server, then puts those results into a chunk of html generated by another script.  The problem is, I can't select with watin any of the elements of this new piece of html.  It can be viewed in the browser, and comes up when I hit F12 and scan through the code, but still WatiN can't see it.

Is this because WatiN only scans through the html source of the page, and not the current version of the HTML?  I think a similar situation would be:

html -

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#foo').html("gak");
</script>
...
<div id="foo">bar</div>
```

then when I try and assert -

```
Assert.IsTrue(browser.Div("foo")).ContainsText("gak"));
```

it will return false.

Any ideas on this? or is my best option to just write a bunch of jQuery, and browser.Eval() it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I test AJAX pages quite a bit.  The key is to wait until the asnyc postback has completed.  If you have

```
Assert.IsFalse(browser.Div("foo")).ContainsText("gak");
browser_action_that_changes_bar_to_gak
>> Here you need to wait <<
Assert.IsTrue(browser.Div("foo")).ContainsText("gak");
```

In the "wait" section you can do a System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(numberOfMilliseconds)  <- this is **not the best way**, but it is really simple.  Once you determine that waiting is what you need to do, a better way to wait is to poll the status rather than way *numberOfMilliseconds* each time.  I believe different AJAX libraries do things differently, but what works for me is **really** similar to this:  http://pushpontech.blogspot.com/2008/04/ajax-issues-with-watin.html

I put the JavaScript into an Eval() in a helper function in the my base Page class rather than having to inject it into every page like the article did.

.

my Base Page class contains:

```
public bool IsInAsyncPostBack()
{
    const string isAsyncPostBackScript = "Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().get_isInAsyncPostBack()";
    return bool.Parse(this.Document.Eval(isAsyncPostBackScript));
}
```

And then my WaitForAsyncPostback is basically the same as in the linked post, but I added a max wait time.  Before going to Page classes (awesome; do it!) I made these static functions somewhere else and it worked too.

Answer (score 2):

This is almost surely a **timing issue**.  The jQuery has not updated when you test.  Rather than introducing any artificial pause or wait it's best to wait for something to show that your AJAX has worked as expected.

In this case a **WaitUntil** should do the job nicely:

```
Assert.IsTrue(browser.Div("foo")).WaitUntil(c => c.Text.Contains("gak")));
```

This works for most updates and the like.  Another common waiting pattern is on data loading say, where you'd have a spinning wheel displayed.  Then you could wait until this wheel is gone with a something like:

```
WaitUntil(c => c.Style.Display == "none");
```